# Cyclic group and permutation group question

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm having trouble solving the following question from a math competition. I have provided a solution below, but I was wondering if someone could please try to explain the solution to me.

[image]

[image]

---

Here is the solution that is provided:

[image]

Could someone please explain this to me? I do not have too much abstract algebra background, but I'm willing to look stuff up and learn.

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you familiar with composition of permutations?

Comment: Perhaps put the problem aside, and learn the basics of Group Theory, including the basics of permutation groups. Then look at the problem again.

Comment: As a pedestrian alternative, make a table with $10$ columns and $17$ rows, where the columns numbers are the posts numbers, the row numbers are the round numbers from $0$ to $16$, and the value in each cell of the table is the cat number in that cell in a given round. If you fill in the table, you'll be able to verify that row $16$ is the same as row $0$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with them. I am reading about them now

Comment: Take your time. This is not material that can be learned in a day. Use a book, and work through the relevant chapters. Make sure to do exercises to confirm your learning.

Comment: How did they multiply the rules? Is that a direct product?